# query select single class from many

Tags: jquery

i am in need of help badly 
i have a table and i need to get two span tags form just the row 
where the check box has been selected and make them a variable

here is the table and the classes i need are .downpayment and .fullpay but only for the row that is checked

if it help here is a screen cap of that table to help understand

```
<table class="table">
<tr class="planbreak">
    <td rowspan="2"> <input type="checkbox" name="plan"> </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="plan-title">Premium Add - Stated</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="plan-right"><span class="badge"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modifiyvehicle">T &amp; C</a></span> 60/125000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="plan-info">
    <td>10% Down: $<span class="downpayment">262.00</span></td>
    <td class="text-center">18 Months: $131.15</td>
    <td class="text-center">12 Months: $196.73</td>
    <td class="text-center">Full Pay: $<span class="fullpay">2,623.00</span></td>
    <td class="text-right">Coverage miles: 15,000 (yr)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="planbreak">
    <td rowspan="2"> <input type="checkbox" name="plan" > </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="plan-title">Premium Add - Stated</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="plan-right"><span class="badge"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modifiyvehicle">T &amp; C</a></span> 60/100000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="plan-info">
    <td>10% Down: $<span class="downpayment">262.00</span></td>
    <td class="text-center">18 Months: $131.15</td>
    <td class="text-center">12 Months: $196.73</td>
    <td class="text-center">Full Pay: $<span class="fullpay">2,623.00</span></td>
    <td class="text-right">Coverage miles: 15,000 (yr)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i have tried this

```
downpay = $(this).closest('tr').next().next('span').text();
```

but doesn't work and

```
downpay = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('span').text();
```

this just returns all classes

[image: screencapof table layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second try is almost correct, just add the class to the `span` selector:

```
downpay = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('span.downpayment').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var downpay = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('span.downpayment').text();
```

to get the `.downpayment` text and :

```
var fullpay = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('span.fullpay').text();
```

to get the `.fullpay` text

Comment: thanks felix that is exactly what i did thanks for adding the full pay

Answer (score 0):

```
var this_row = $(this).parents('tr'),//Get the selected row
    downpay  = this_row.next().find('span.downpayment').text(),//.downpayment text
    fullpay  = this_row.next().find('span.fullpay').text();//.fullpay text
```